# macOS want to make changes.Enter an administrator name and password to allow this box keeps popping up

Tags: macbook, macos-catalina, macbook-air, keychain-access

This box keeps popping up. I've read other answers to similar problem without success.

I've gone to keychain > system > certificates > my computer > certificate with an arrow > private key > access control (where I see written under 'name' com.apple.identity.export) and changed it to 'allow all applications to access this item.
This didn't solve the problem.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your account administrator on this computer, is the obvious first question we need answered. Did you purchase this computer new, or used? Or is it your computer or does it belong to a company you work for or a school you attend?

Comment: I bought the computer new and had it for some years since early 2015. The admin password is the same as it's always been. At one point I recall having a problem with keychains about two years ago and created a temporary one. But no, it's my private computer, not a workone.

Comment: Any updates, were you able to resolve this issue?